# Copying change list history in perforce

Tags: copy, perforce, history

Just wondering if anyone knows how to copy a folder from on //depot/one/proj to //depot/two/proj with all the changelist history for files withing //depot/one/proj

Thanks,
sam

Comment: `p4 integrate //depot/one/proj/... //depot/two/proj/...`?

Answer (score 1):

`p4 populate` is a fast way to make a new branch.  The files in `//depot/two/proj` will have merge history back to the original folder.

There's also `p4 duplicate`, which makes a real copy, not a branch.  But that's not often used.

Comment: Is `duplicate` deprecated? I can find no reference to it on p4 website and `p4 help duplicate` includes message "unsupported". Additionally is `copy` the same as an integrate followed by `p4 resolve -ay` ("accept yours")?